# ace editor setting theme has a delay

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

when I use **ace** editor in my project,I set the theme to `tommorow_night`, but every time the web page firstly set the editor to the default theme, and then about a second later changed to `tommorow_night`.

This caused the editor firstly is an empty editor,then it turned to default theme, and then quickly changed to tomorrow_night.

My code is just as below:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/tomorrow_night");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/c_cpp");
```

Is there a way to disable the default theme and just load the tomorrow_night theme directly?

Answer (score 1):

Include the `tomorrow_night.js` file after ace.js, that way when you call `setTheme("ace/theme/tomorrow_night")` it will set the theme immediately, instead of waiting for the file to load.

This will prevent the default theme, but won't prevent the empty editor appearing since it appears happens before `ace.edit` call